# Filter Mapping for Tomcat 6.0.35 CrsfPreventionFilter

Tags: tomcat, filter, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm attempting to introduce Apache Tomcat's [6.0.35] Cross-Site Prevention Filter into an existing web app.

I've modified the web.xml by adding the  and  tags and I can get the app to deploy and function as expected with a mapping `<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>`.

But if I use a mapping of `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` or `<servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>`, the filter is apparently active for the mapped requests, but it rejects requests for any resource other than the initialized entry point *even though the current nonce is passed in the request*. I.e the response is 403/forbidden.

Suggestions anyone?